# Start index is less than zero, if all the checkbox is not checked in checkbox list

Tags: c#

```
StringBuilder sbOccupation = new StringBuilder();
foreach (ListItem li in cblOccupation.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        sbOccupation.Append(li.Text);
        sbOccupation.Append(",");
    }
}
property.Occupation=sbOccupation.ToString().Remove(sbOccupation.ToString().LastIndexOf(","), 1);
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no checkboxes are checked, then

`li.Selected` is false for each

`li in cblOccupation.Items`, and then

`.LastIndexOf(","), 1)` produces the error since

`sbOccupation.Append(",");`

never happened.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing has been appended to `sbOccuption`, then it will be empty - so `LastIndexOf(',')` will return -1, which isn't a valid first argument to [`string.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove.aspx).

Given that you know it will always be the *last character* of the result, you could just use:

```
if (sbOccuptation.Length > 0)
{
    // Trim the trailing comma
    sbOccupation--;
}
string text = sbOccupation.ToString();
```

However, it would be simpler just to use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) and LINQ:

```
// This replaces *all* your code
property.Occupation = string.Join(",", cblOccuptation.Items 
                                                     .Cast<ListItem>()
                                                     .Where(li => li.Selected)
                                                     .Select(li => li.Text));
```

If you're using .NET 3.5, you'll need a call to `ToArray` after the `Select` call, but that's simple enough.